# Keychain with Muktzeh

Tags: muktzeh, shabbat

If I have a Key chain with Muktzeh on it can I use the keys on the  Key chain?

Comment: Also see: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9294/keychain-with-muktzeh-items-e-g-usb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the other keys on the key chain (Shmiras Shabbos K'Hilchoso Tikuniim U'Miluyim Perek 20 Note 270) however you should not hold the keychain by the Muktza key.

Comment: Suppose the extra item, for example a chipped key or a fob, might be a mukzeh hasoren kis.